# Get fit rectangle on PNG image

Tags: java, image-processing, png

I have a PNG image and I want to get that rectangle to fit visible image on it.

Here my image example:

[image]

I have image dimension bigger than image inside it.

Outer rectangle is the real width and height of my image. And I want make rectangle depend on visible image like inner rectangle.

I'm using Java . How could I do that?

Comment: Oke...

Sorry2
I'm new in here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it yourself, my idea is:

Starting at the top of the image:

1. Scan the topmost line of the image and count the number of distinct colors. You may want to define "distinct" with a bit of fuzziness here.
2. If there is only one color, remember that color. Otherwise you are finished for the top.
3. Scan the next line. If it has only one color, and if this color is the same as the one in the topmost line, continue with step 3.
4. You are done. The current line is the first "relevant" image line.

Repeat the above steps for the other borders of the image, and you are done.

Note: To be able to test your algorithm properly you should split the whole task into several ones:

1. `Rectangle visibleRectangle(BufferedImage image)`; this is a good interface for automated testing.
2. `BufferedImage crop(BufferedImage image, Rectangle image)`; the rest of the work, which should be fairly simple to program.

Comment: I use PixelGrabber and it look find. I got that pixel which have transparency have zero integer.